# is the probability of selecting a completely even family $\frac1{2^ n}$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

let $A$ be a set with $N$ elements, and for $0 \le M_{\mathfrak{B}} \le 2^n$ let $\mathfrak{B} =\{B_j\}_{j=0 \cdots M_{\mathfrak{B}}}$ be a a random variable whose value is a family of subsets of $A$, with a distribution determined by the stipulation that any element in $\mathfrak{P}^2(A)$ (the power set of the power set of $A$) is equally likely to be selected.

call $\mathfrak{B} \in \mathfrak{P}^2$ *completely even* if every element of $A$ which belongs to at least one of the $B_j \in \mathfrak{B}$ actually occurs in an *even* number of them.

**question 1** is it true that the probability that a randomly chosen element of the powerset of the powerset of a set with $n$ elements is completely even, is  $\frac1{2^ n}$?

my current reason for thinking so is (it seems to me at present!) that we know the subsets of a set are an abelian group under the operation of disjoint union, so, representing this op by the addition sign, then we may define a surjective homomorphism:
$$
\Phi:\mathfrak{P}^2(A) \to \mathfrak{P}(A)
$$
by:
$$
\Phi(\mathfrak{B}) = \sum_{B \in \mathfrak{B}} B
$$
and the completely even families are precisely the kernel of $\Phi$. so the number of completely even families $|Ker{\Phi}|=E(n) = |\mathfrak{P}^2(A)|/|\mathfrak{P}(A)|$ and the probability of choosing one out of all the elements of $\mathfrak{P}^2(A)$ is $\frac{E(n)}{|\mathfrak{P}^2(A)|} = \frac1{|\mathfrak{P}(A)|}=\frac1{2^n}$

**question 2** *if* the above reasoning is sound, is there a conceptually simpler combinatorial argument for this claim?

FOOTNOTE as an illustration, take the case $n=3$, with, say, $A=\{1,2,3\}$. then $\mathfrak{p}(A)$ has the eight elements $\emptyset,1,2,3,12,23,31,123$ ,(where the $\{$ and $\}$ have been omitted. in $\mathfrak{P}^2(A)$ we note the following completely even elements:

firstly the empty family, and the family consisting of $\emptyset$ alone. then the following $15$ combinations, which may also be combined with the empty set to give a further $15$. this gives $32$ elements $=2^{2^3-3}$
$$
12+23+31\\
123+1+2+3 \\
12+23+31+123+1+2+3 \\
\\
12+1+2\\
23+2+3\\
31+3+1\\
\\
\\
12+13+2+3\\
\\
23+21+3+1\\
\\
31+32+1+2\\
\\
1 +23 +123 \\
2 +31 +123 \\
3 +32 +123 \\
12+13+1+123\\
23+21+2+123\\
32+31+3+123\\
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you'll like this (which is conceptually identical but involves no explicit group theory):

Let $C$ be a subset of $A$, and say that a family $\mathfrak{B} \in \mathfrak{P}^2$ is $C-parity$ if every element in $C$ belongs to an even number of the $B_i$ in $\mathfrak{B}$, and every element not in $C$ belongs to an odd number of the $B_i$ in $\mathfrak{B}$. The totally even families are then the same as being $A-$parity. Now one just has to show that the number of $C-$parity families is the same as the number of $A-$parity families, for any $C$.

To prove this, simply note that any $C-$parity family $\mathfrak{B}$ can be turned into an $A-$parity family by either removing $C'= A \backslash C$, if $C'$ is in $\mathfrak{B}$, or adding $C'$ if it is not. This process will also turn an $A-$parity family into a $C-$parity family, and it is involutive (doing it twice results in the identity), so it is a bijection between the two sets.

Comment: very neat. should it be the complement of $C$ that is added or removed, as defined? your answer resolves my initial uneasiness that there should be as many "totally even" elements in $\mathfrak{P}^2(A)$ as there are. (though at present, after removing duplicates, i am three short in the above list ;-)

Comment: Yeah of course, edited.

Comment: your treatment also shows that the singletons of $\mathfrak{P}^2(A)$ form a 'natural' set of cosets for the quotient, which is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{P}(A)$. so the 'new' structure in $\mathfrak{P}^2(A)$ is precisely in the subgroup of completely-even (or A-parity) elements. i think that is the 'insight' i was groping for, so thanks very much for your help!